Hide 'District' name from 'City' dropdown - woocommerce
How to hide the 'District' name that is shown with 'City' in the city drop-down on the cart and checkout pages in WooCommerce?
I need to show the city without "district" name in cart and checkout page. Any ideas?

First, you should specify if you are using Classic Cart and checkout or Blocks version. Then provide some screenshots and/or a live links. Note that cart and checkout blocks allow very few customizations. Nobody can guess things by magic.
